# how do i fix a "NameError: name 'thing' is not defined" when calling a function ?

Tags: python, function

i am learning python from code academy, and i'm trying to complete their review assignment. 
I am supposed to define a function, and then set up a if/else loop to check the type of input i get, and then return either absolute value of an int/float or an error message.

I tried to look at similar questions, but i don't understand those codes are a lot more complicated than i can understand O_O. I looked at the function module lessons again, but i think i followed the function making pattern correctly ? Is there supposed to be an extra line before i call the function ? I tried to keep going, but then i am gettnig this same error message in the other exercises.

I would appreciate any responses :)

```
def distance_from_zero(thing):
     thing = input 
     if type(thing) != int or float: 
         return "Not an integer or float!"
     else:
         return abs(thing)
distance_from_zero(thing)
```

Comment: You simply do not have `thing` defined in `distance_from_zero(thing)`.

Comment: `input` is not defined.

Comment: to define a variable, i cannot set to equal input ?

Comment: `type(thing) != int or float` will evaluate to one of `(True, float)`, both of which will cause the `if` path to be taken. You want `type(thing) not in (int, float)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to use the input function to get a value from the user ?
if so, you must add parenthesis to it:

```
thing = input()
# If you're using python 2.X, you should use raw_input instead:
# thing = raw_input()
```

Also, you don't need the input parameter if that's what you're trying to do.

If you do mean `input` to be a parameter, then you're trying to use variables before defining them. `distance_from_zero(thing)` can't work since `thing` hasn't been defined outside your function, so you should either define that variable first or call it with a litteral value:

```
thing = 42
distance_from_zero(thing)
# or
distance_from_zero(42)
```

Comment: i understand the error message now, thanks to your explanation =)

Answer (score 1):

You do not define the `thing`. Please try

```
def distance_from_zero(thing): 
     if type(thing) != int or float: 
         return "Not an integer or float!"
     else:
         return abs(thing)

thing = 1
distance_from_zero(thing)
```

Or your meaning is this, accepting the user input?

```
def distance_from_zero():
     thing = int(input())
     if type(thing) != int or float: 
         return "Not an integer or float!"
     else:
         return abs(thing)
distance_from_zero()
```

And your code `if type(thing) != int or float:` will always go to `True` for it is `if (type(thing) != int) or float`. Change it to `if not isinstance(thing, (int, float)):`.

Answer (score 1):

`thing` isn't defined when you pass it to the distance_from_zero function?

```
def distance_from_zero(input):
     if type(input) != int or float: 
         return "Not an integer or float!"
     else:
         return abs(input)

thing = 5
distance_from_zero(thing)
```